# What's the smallest value of the greatest number in the sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let's suppose that $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ are distinct $3$-digit numbers such that $a_0+a_1+a_2+ a_3+ a_4 = 745$. What's the smallest value of the greatest number in the sum?

We can let $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 149$ but since they're supposed to be distinct, we shall consider a sequence of numbers $a_i = a+i$ for $i\in \{0, \cdots 4\}$ so that

$$a_0+(a_0+1)+\cdots (a_0+4) = 745$$

From which we conclude that $a_0 = 147$ and $a_4 = a_0 + 4 = 151$ as the smallest value. But how does one prove this?

Comment: Don't work with $a_0$, $a_0+1$, ..., but with $a_2-2$, $a_2-1$, $a_2$, $a_2+1$ and $a_2+2$: the adding will be so much easier to handle :-)

Comment: @Dominique Thanks for your so valuable piece of advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wlog, $a_0<a_1<\dots<a_4$, hence
$$\begin{align}a_3&\le a_4-1,\\a_2&\le a_3-1\le a_4-2,\\a_1&\le a_2-1\le a_4-3,\\a_0&\le a_1-1\le a_4-4\end{align}$$
and therefore,
$$745=a_4+\dots+a_0\le5a_4-(1+2+3+4)$$
i.e.
$$a_4\ge\frac{745+10}5=151.$$